# Correct way of writing a conditional filter in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For writing a conditional filter in a controller in rails, the recommended way seems to be using a lambda like this:

```
before_action :authenticate_user, unless: -> { !Rails.env.production? && ENV['DISABLE_LOGIN'] == 'true' }
```

While the above seems to be the correct way of doing it, the following situation seems to also work well in the case of my example:

```
before_action :authenticate_user unless !Rails.env.production? && ENV['DISABLE_LOGIN'] == 'true'
```

What I would like to understand is what are the differences between the 2 approaches and if the second approach can yield an undesired outcome in certain scenarios.

Comment: I think that the first is processed for each request where the second is processed once when the file is loaded. If you don't change the environment variable for the lifetime of the application then they both seem to be equivalent except the second may be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me start of by adding some parentheses and some newlines to better display the difference between the two.

```
before_action(
  :authenticate_user,
  unless: -> { !Rails.env.production? && ENV['DISABLE_LOGIN'] == 'true' }
)

# vs

unless !Rails.env.production? && ENV['DISABLE_LOGIN'] == 'true'
  before_action(:authenticate_user)
end
```

The first version, with the `unless` as part of the options, always defines the `before_action :authenticate_user`. The unless lambda is executed for each request and `authenticate_user` only called if the lambda resolves into a falsy value.

The second version makes the check controller is defined. Based on those checks the `before_action :authenticated` is either defined or not defined. Note that the checks made in this version cannot use `params` since it uses the controller class context, only instances of a controller class have access to web-request.

---

Since your condition only uses environment variables and doesn't any web-request data, the second option is the faster one. However if you change the environment variables while the server is running you would need to reload the controller class (by restarting the server).

If you use the first option you could change the environment variables, and have them effect the controller without restart. Due to the check being made for each request.